# Aws Glue Crawler is not updating the table after 1st crawl

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue-data-catalog

I am adding a new file in parquet format which is created by a Glue Databrew in my S3 folder. The new file has the same schema as the previous file. But when I am running the Crawler for the 2nd time it is neither updating the table nor creating a new one in the data catalog. Also when I am crawling both the files together, both of them are getting added.

Log File is giving the following information:
INFO : Created partitions with values [[New file name]] for table
BENCHMARK : Finished writing to Catalog

I have tried with and without "Create a single schema for each S3 path". But the crawler is not updating the table with the new file. Sooner I will add new files on a daily basis to do my analysis. Any solution?

Comment: Have you tried checking the table version to see if it got updated? Also have you tried querying the table to see if it is giving results from new file. How many rows present in the new file generated?

Comment: Hello @PrabhakarReddy. Yes, I have checked the table version, it is not getting updated and also the number of rows is the same as the first file even after 2nd crawl.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to approach this issue in my opinion is to use AWS DataBrew output to Data Catalog directly. Data Catalog can be updated either by the crawler or by DataBrew directly but the recommended practice is that you employ any one of those mechanisms not both.

Can you try running the job with output as your data catalog and let Databrew manage your catalog? It should update your catalog table with right data/files.

Comment: Hello @Nitya. Thank you for your reply! Do I need to attach a policy to my Databrew role to write the output directly to Data Catalog. I tried this and it gave me an error. "databrew-role/DataBrewAccessTestSession is not authorized to perform: glue:GetTable on resource"

Comment: Off the top, that is about right, your role needs to to have glue:GetTable and glue:UpdateTable permissions.